# CSS - Elements not stacking on top of each other when re-sizing in Wordpress

Tags: php, css, wordpress, responsive-design

I'm applying some media queries styling rules to a wordpress site. One section has two rows with 3 x 4 columns. Within each row there's an image with a paragraph underneath. When I re-size the page I need each image to stack on top of its respective paragraph. I had this working on my front-end test site but when I've come to test it on my wordpress site they stack alongside each other in a row.

Here's a code snippet -

```css
body {
  margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
}

.container {
  margin: auto;
  max-width: 100%;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
}

section#team {
  height: 800px;
  max-width: 100%;
}

section#team div.row {
  height: 350px;
}

#team .four {
  position: relative;
  width: 320px;
  padding: 30px;
}

#team h4 {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 30px;
}

#team img {
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 50%;
  left: 40%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

#team p {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 10px;
  margin-top: 100px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1000px) {
  div.container {
    float: none;
    margin: 0;
    width: calc(100% - 40px);
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }
  div.column {
    float: none;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  body {
    max-width: 500px;
    border: 1px dashed #ccc;
    min-height: 400px;
  }
  
  section#team {
    float: none;
    height: auto;
  }
  
  #team .four {
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    position: relative;
    transform: translate(-30%, -5%);
  }
}
```

```html
<body>
  <section id="team">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="twelve columns">
        <h4>MEET THE TEAM</h4>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="four columns">
            <img src="https://static.pexels.com/photos/99551/hot-air-balloon-valley-sky-99551.jpeg" alt="Meet Tim" style="width:100px;height:100px;">
            <p>Praesent sodales, leo at pellentesque pellentesque, nunc erat dapibus nunc, ut congue libero lorem in orci. Suspendisse potenti. Quisque facilisis mauris in vestibulum tempor.</br>Praesent sodales, leo at pellentesque pellentesque, nunc erat
              dapibus nunc, ut congue libero lorem in orci. Suspendisse potenti. Quisque facilisis mauris in vestibulum tempor.
            </p>
          </div>
          <div class="four columns">
            <img src="https://static.pexels.com/photos/99551/hot-air-balloon-valley-sky-99551.jpeg" alt="Meet Tim" style="width:100px;height:100px;">
            <p>Praesent sodales, leo at pellentesque pellentesque, nunc erat dapibus nunc, ut congue libero lorem in orci. Suspendisse potenti. Quisque facilisis mauris in vestibulum tempor.</br>Praesent sodales, leo at pellentesque pellentesque, nunc erat
              dapibus nunc, ut congue libero lorem in orci. Suspendisse potenti. Quisque facilisis mauris in vestibulum tempor.
            </p>
          </div>
          <div class="four columns">
            <img src="https://static.pexels.com/photos/99551/hot-air-balloon-valley-sky-99551.jpeg" alt="Meet Tim" style="width:100px;height:100px;">
            <p>Praesent sodales, leo at pellentesque pellentesque, nunc erat dapibus nunc, ut congue libero lorem in orci. Suspendisse potenti. Quisque facilisis mauris in vestibulum tempor.</br>Praesent sodales, leo at pellentesque pellentesque, nunc erat
              dapibus nunc, ut congue libero lorem in orci. Suspendisse potenti. Quisque facilisis mauris in vestibulum tempor.</p>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
          <div class="four columns">
            <img src="https://static.pexels.com/photos/99551/hot-air-balloon-valley-sky-99551.jpeg" alt="Meet Tim" style="width:100px;height:100px;">
            <p>Praesent sodales, leo at pellentesque pellentesque, nunc erat dapibus nunc, ut congue libero lorem in orci. Suspendisse potenti. Quisque facilisis mauris in vestibulum tempor.</br>Praesent sodales, leo at pellentesque pellentesque, nunc erat
              dapibus nunc, ut congue libero lorem in orci. Suspendisse potenti. Quisque facilisis mauris in vestibulum tempor.</p>
          </div>
          <div class="four columns">
            <img src="https://static.pexels.com/photos/99551/hot-air-balloon-valley-sky-99551.jpeg" alt="Meet Tim" style="width:100px;height:100px;">
            <p>Praesent sodales, leo at pellentesque pellentesque, nunc erat dapibus nunc, ut congue libero lorem in orci. Suspendisse potenti. Quisque facilisis mauris in vestibulum tempor.</br>Praesent sodales, leo at pellentesque pellentesque, nunc erat
              dapibus nunc, ut congue libero lorem in orci. Suspendisse potenti. Quisque facilisis mauris in vestibulum tempor.</p>
          </div>
          <div class="four columns">
            <img src="https://static.pexels.com/photos/99551/hot-air-balloon-valley-sky-99551.jpeg" alt="Meet Tim" style="width:100px;height:100px;">
            <p>Praesent sodales, leo at pellentesque pellentesque, nunc erat dapibus nunc, ut congue libero lorem in orci. Suspendisse potenti. Quisque facilisis mauris in vestibulum tempor.</br>Praesent sodales, leo at pellentesque pellentesque, nunc erat
              dapibus nunc, ut congue libero lorem in orci. Suspendisse potenti. Quisque facilisis mauris in vestibulum tempor.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
</body>
```

I don't know if I need a different set of rules for my wordpress site - here's the php code for that page -

```
<?php /* Template Name: Meet the team */ ?>
<?php get_header(); ?>

<?php get_template_part('topimage-about'); ?>
    <section id="team">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="twelve columns">
                             <h4>MEET THE TEAM</h4>
                <div class="row">
                        <div class="four columns">
                                <?php if( get_field('team_img_1') ): ?>

                                <img src="<?php the_field('team_img_1'); ?>" style="width:100px;height:100px;" />

                                <?php endif; ?>
                                <p><?php the_field('team_bio_1'); ?>
                                </p> 
                        </div>        
                        <div class="four columns">
                               <?php if( get_field('team_img_2') ): ?>

                                <img src="<?php the_field('team_img_2'); ?>" style="width:100px;height:100px;" />

                                <?php endif; ?>
                                <p><?php the_field('team_bio_2'); ?>
                                </p> 
                        </div>
                        <div class="four columns">    
                                <?php if( get_field('team_img_3') ): ?>

                                <img src="<?php the_field('team_img_3'); ?>" style="width:100px;height:100px;" />

                                <?php endif; ?>
                                <p><?php the_field('team_bio_3'); ?>
                                </p>
                        </div>    
                </div>

                <div class="row">
                        <div class="four columns">    
                                <?php if( get_field('team_img_4') ): ?>

                                <img src="<?php the_field('team_img_4'); ?>" style="width:100px;height:100px;" />

                                <?php endif; ?>
                                <p><?php the_field('team_bio_4'); ?>
                                </p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="four columns">    
                                <?php if( get_field('team_img_5') ): ?>

                                <img src="<?php the_field('team_img_5'); ?>" style="width:100px;height:100px;" />

                                <?php endif; ?>
                                <p><?php the_field('team_bio_5'); ?>
                                </p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="four columns">    
                                <?php if( get_field('team_img_6') ): ?>

                                <img src="<?php the_field('team_img_6'); ?>" style="width:100px;height:100px;" />

                                <?php endif; ?>
                                <p><?php the_field('team_bio_6'); ?>
                                </p>
                        </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>                
    </section>

       <?php get_template_part('form'); ?>





<?php get_sidebar(); ?>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

UPDATE - The code provided in the fiddle has fixed my media queries but my main styles now not working. This is how it looks now at full stretch -

[image: meet the team - desktop]

Comment: I don't see any style rules specified that would adjust the layout as you're intending but at some point you would probably need to declare `display: block; width: 100%;` on `#team .four`

Comment: you need to add section#team div.row {height: auto;} to your media-querie as well - alse it doesn't have an appropriate height.

Comment: which will force your row, to belive that it only has 350px height on mobile. which will cause the next row to move up to that point. 
you can see it if you add overflow hidden to your row

Comment: @Stender So I need a separate rule for div.row?

Comment: you already have one in your normal style : section#team div.row {height: 350px;} - this needs to be negated in your media querie

Comment: @UncaughtTypeError Do I even need the position:relative rule?

Comment: since you are using position absolute on your image, you might want to keep the position relative. but you can always just test and undo.

Comment: @Mike.Whitehead You'll probably need to remove the `absolute` position declared on the thumbnail images at this stage anyway - so it may no longer be necessary. But if it isn't causing any harm, I can't see why you couldn't leave it as is.

Comment: @UncaughtTypeError How do I 'remove' it ? Is there an alternate rule for media queries? The position rules have really caught me out when doing this exercise. also, none of the above suggestions have had any effect. Maybe I need to look at specificity.

Comment: You would have to overwrite it with another `position` rule, but you shouldn't need to do that unless you specifically need them positioned anything other than `relative`, which I don't think is necessary in this case. Better to just keep everything in the logical flow of the document. What above suggestions are you referring to specifically? If it's a specificity issue you'll be able to see that easily in your dev tools, since those custom rules would be over-qualified by other rules (lined out with a trike-through)

Comment: take a look at this fiddle - might give you an idea on how it could be written - It is your code with some css tweaks. there is no need for absolute, transform, inline-block, height, etc.. https://jsfiddle.net/3cpL7d2a/1/

Comment: @Stender That's worked for my media queries but broken my main styles...

Comment: @Stender I've put an image above as to how it looks now at full stretch. It looks like the row will only pull so far?

Comment: @Stender Don't worry - I adjusted the calc down to 30%. Put the fiddle up as an answer and I'll mark it correct.

Comment: @Mike.Whitehead No problems - good luck with the rest of the site

Comment: @Stender Thanks. I have one last thing on RWD to do then I'm pressing send.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is intended to help you finding the right path - it is not complete, but it will give you an idea. check the fiddle, and play around :)

I have to post some code, to answer with a fiddle. but one of your problems was that you had a fixed height in your normal styles

```
@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    section#team div.row {
          height:auto;
    }
}
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3cpL7d2a/1/)

Glad that it worked for you.